# Can not text message most people with iPhones since iOS 8

Tags: messages, ios

We do not use iMessage in our house (we have our reasons). My son updated to iOS 8 and now he can not text most people with iPhones. His phone keeps telling him he *has to* use iMessage.

Comment: How did you text with iOS7?

Answer (score 1):

Settings => Messages => Toggle off "iMessage". Works just fine (just tested it).

Answer (score 1):

Turn iMessage on then turn it back off. It happened to me too. Apparently it thinks "who wouldn't want to use iMessage?" So it just pretends that it is on until you turn it on. It made me really mad for a few minutes.